# Blown ferrite bead, need replacement

Tags: emi-filtering

I'm repairing a Nintendo switch dock and I found that a ferrite bead has blown.  The problem is that I don´t really know how to identify the ferrite bead that I need.  Can anyone help me? If it helps the IC receiver is the STDP2550.

[image: I dont really know how to measure it.]

Comment: It is more likely to be a dual common-mode choke as it has 8 pins. If it had a groung terminal I would say it is an ESD protection device.

Comment: If you can find an "application note" for the STDP2550 MyDP to HDMI convertor, it may well have a reference to the exact device you need.